# How to dismiss VIewController iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I am new to iOS development. I am developing an application using iOS Swift. I have 3 view controllers viewController1, viewController2, viewController3. 
When I click from viewController1 its move to viewController2. By using the following code

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let secondViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewController2")
        presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Now I am moving from viewController2 to viewController3 by using the following code

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("viewController3", sender: scoreColorArray);
```

It's all fine. Now I want to back from viewController3 to viewController1.  My problem it is not going to viewController1 it is going to viewController2. I know the reason viewController2 not dismissed.

**I want to dismiss the current view controller and start new one**. How can I do it? I know there is some ways to do it, please someone help me to finds the issue.

Comment: call dismissViewController on the one you presented

Comment: "I want to dismiss the second one and go to third one". When I call dismiss from second it is not going to third view controller.

Comment: Your comment is a bit confusing. You want to go from VC3 to VC1, is that right? If VC1 presents VC2 and VC2 presents VC3 then calling `self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated` on VC3 should take you to VC1.

Comment: @spassas Exactly this is what I wanted. Could you please add this in answer. It is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your presentation sequence is `VC1` -> `VC2` -> `VC3` you need to call `self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerA‌​animated` on `VC3`, traversing this way your sequence in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using delegate.

- You send delegate call from `controller 2` to `controller 1` for dismiss
  controller 2.
- After dismiss success, you will push `controller 3` from `controller 1`

You can look my demo for this case: [Demo Pushview](https://github.com/vienvu89/DemoPushView)